# Blazor: NavMenu disappearing when I press F5 to refresh (Issue: Datatables.net)

Tags: c#, .net-core, datatables, blazor-server-side

I have a page that uses the searchable table template from Datatables.net.  During the OnAfterRenderAsync process where it re-renders the table, in the console, you can see it disconnect from the server, and then re-connect 2 seconds later.

It appears that, during this disconnect, the controls in the NavMenu disappear, although the OnInitializedAsync does **NOT** re-fire. If you navigate normally, the menu options remain visible.  It's literally just if you use F5 or the refresh button.  If I disable the OnAfterRenderAsync method, the menus no longer disappear... and, lastly, if I hit the back button in the browser, and refresh with F5, the nav menu will re-appear.

The value for if access is allowed is determined with:

```
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService oLocalStore
```

and

```
IsManager = await oLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("Key tag here");
```

For which the controls then sit inside:

```
 @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsManager))
 {
      @if (IsManager.ToUpper() == "TRUE")
      {
           <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Self Service</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                     <a @onclick="collapsedNavBar" class="dropdown-item" href="/PasswordReset"><span class="oi oi-reload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Password Reset</a>                                        
                     <a @onclick="collapsedNavBar" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                     <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                     <a @onclick="collapsedNavBar" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Manager Notes</a>
                     <a @onclick="collapsedNavBar" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Company Policies</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
      }
 }
```

On the pages using datatables.net's template, the OnAfterRenderAsync() looks like this:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var jQuery = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("$", "table");
        await jQuery.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTable");          
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround with Datatables.net that can get it to function properly with Blazor server-side?  Or, is there a solid alternative for paging, sorting, and searching I can replace it with?

Comment: does it re-renders the table every time OnAfterRender is fired or on firstRender only? Show the overrides on your post please. You can also use OnParametersSet(), which I find better to your case scenario.

Comment: @LuccaFerri It does re-render it each time the page is refreshed.  Given Issues I'm seeing with larger data sets (even just 14k rows takes 12 seconds **on a good PC** to load the page), I'm thinking a custom pagination/sorting/searching is going to be necessary so it doesn't try visually render the entire dataset at once.

Comment: this is the way to go. & are you sure to use jquery? you can do most of it natively!

Comment: No, this was not the best way to go.  II found a perfect solution using Radzen... answering with the sample code now.

Answer (score 0):

An instant-render mode was achieved using Radzen's grid solution.

UI:

```
<RadzenGrid AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" AllowSorting="true" Data="@PreOrders" TItem="PreOrder" AllowFiltering="true" AllowColumnResize="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" style="max-width:580px">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="PreOrder" Context="preOrder" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
            <Template Context="preOrder">
                <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="open_with" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => GetPreOrderByID(preOrder))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                </RadzenButton>
            </Template>
            <EditTemplate Context="preOrder">
                <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="open_with" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => GetPreOrderByID(preOrder))">
                </RadzenButton>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenGridColumn>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="PreOrder" Property="PreOrderTemplateID" Title="ID" Width="80px"></RadzenGridColumn>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="PreOrder" Property="TemplateInfo" Title="Template Info#"></RadzenGridColumn>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="PreOrder" Context="preOrder" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="60px">
            <Template Context="preOrder">
                <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="highlight_off" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DelPreOrder(preOrder))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                </RadzenButton>
            </Template>
            <EditTemplate Context="preOrder">
                <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Icon="highlight_off" Size="ButtonSize.Small" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => DelPreOrder(preOrder))">
                </RadzenButton>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenGridColumn>
    </Columns>

</RadzenGrid>
```

Code:

```
@code {
    private List<string> Makes { get; set; }
    private List<string> Models { get; set; }
    private List<string> Trims { get; set; }
    private List<string> CarClasses { get; set; }
    private List<string> EngineTypes { get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<PreOrder> PreOrders { get; set; }
    private PreOrder PO = new PreOrder();
    private string StatusMessage = "";
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Makes = _fleet.GetVehicleMakes();
        CarClasses = _fleet.GetVehicleCarClasses();
        EngineTypes = _fleet.GetVehicleEngineTypes();
        PO.Make = "";
        PreOrders = await Task.Run(() => _fleet.GetTemplates());   
        StatusMessage = "Data Loaded Successfully";
    }
    private async void GetPreOrderByID(PreOrder preOrder)
    {
        PO = _fleet.GetTemplateByID(preOrder.PreOrderTemplateID);    
        Models = _fleet.GetVehicleModels(PO.Make);
        Trims = _fleet.GetVehicleTrims(PO.Make);
    }
    private async void DelPreOrder(PreOrder preOrder)
    {        
        try
        {
            _fleet.DeleteTemplate(preOrder.PreOrderTemplateID);
            PreOrders = _fleet.GetTemplates();   
            StatusMessage = "PreOrder Template: " + preOrder.PreOrderTemplateID.ToString() + " Deleted Successfully at: " + DateTime.Now;
            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusMessage = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
    }
    private async void AddPreOrders()
    {
        try
        {
            string User = await oLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("User");
            _fleet.AddTemplate(PO, User);
            StatusMessage = "Data Added Successfully at: " + DateTime.Now;
            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });         
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusMessage = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
    }       
}
```

And, now, the page can be refreshed however many times, using whatever method, and the navigation menu no longer disappears because there's no client-side re-rendering.